# How to use strongarm module without features module

Tags: strongarm

I am using Drupal 6 and now I am planning to add the [Strongarm](https://drupal.org/project/strongarm) module to my site. Can anyone tell me how to use that, without the dependency of the [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features) module("since feature module is needed to import variables from db" - as per my understanding ). Please guide me on this.

Comment: can anyone tell me what would be the expected result from strongarm module